# How to get link, image data from Lotus Notes RichText field using INTEROP.DOMINO.DLL

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, richtext

In my C# application, I can get attached file data from *Domino RichText* by using simple code, for example:

```
NotesRichTextItem rItem = notesItem as NotesRichTextItem;
NotesRichTextNavigatorClass rNavigator = rItem.CreateNavigator() as NotesRichTextNavigatorClass;
if (rNavigator.FindFirstElement(RT_ELEM.RTELEM_TYPE_FILEATTACHMENT))
 {
   do
    {
       var attachment = rNavigator.GetElement() as NotesEmbeddedObject;
       // and then do something with attachment data
    } while (rNavigator.FindNextElement());
 }
```

then I tried to get *Hyperlink data* or *image data* but I don't find out any idea about that. I have searched in google for many times, but no result.

Answer (score 1):

There are no standard high level APIs from IBM for that, but you have two options:

1. You can use the 3rd party MIDAS Rich Text API from Genii Software.
2. You can use the [NotesDXLExporter class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDXLEXPORTER_CLASS.html) to export the document to DXL, study the XML to identify the information that you are looking for, and write code using standard XML parsing APIs to get it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the two options written by Richard Schwartz, you can also use a similar approach to NotesDXLExporter – web scraping the database content.

Open the document as a web page and parse the HTML using any C# web scraper library (e.g. [IronWebScraper](http://ironsoftware.com/csharp/webscraper/)).

If you don't know how to enable the database for web, read [Setting up a Domino server as a Web server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_settingupadominoserverasawebserver_t.html) and [Domino URL cheat sheet](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/).